# QML MouseArea onEntered hoverEnabled does not work

Tags: qt, qml

a pretty simple scenario, actually:

```
                Text {
                    text: "Hover me!"
                    font.family: "Arial"
                    font.pointSize: 16

                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        hoverEnabled: true

                        onEntered: {
                            parent.color = "#ffffff"
                        }

                        onExited: {
                            parent.color = "#000000"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

As you can see, all i want is that the text color changes when i hover it. However, it works only when i'm holding down my left mouse button. Since i'm pretty new to Qt, i've no idea where the problem could be. I googled all day to find an answer, but everything leads me to the "set hoverEnabled: true" solution, which i'm already using.

I'm working on windows with Qt 2.4.1 including VPlay (doesn't think that VPlay matters here)

Answer (score 2):

From your snippet, it looks like you're not assigning the Text element a size (either explicitly or via anchoring), so it has a width/height of (0,0), which means it will never contain the mouse cursor. Note that in QtQuick, the size of items is not defined by their contents or where they paint (an item can paint anywhere outside of its (position, size) rectangle). An item without explicit width/height attributes or anchoring will have a size of (0,0), no matter how it appears on screen.

In the following example, the mouse area has a size of 360, 360 inherited from its parent rectangle (via `anchors.fill: parent`):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "black"

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        color: mouseArea.containsMouse ? "red" : "white"
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
    }
}
```

}

I preferred the declarative approach using a property binding with containsMouse here, but onEntered/onExited would work as well.

Comment: My code is fine so far, thanks for your response. The issue belongs to V-Play, since V-Play currently does not support hover states in their engine.